# Change the thickness/width of a d3 chart's axis lines without affecting tick labels

Tags: d3.js, typescript, powerbi

I'm working on a Power Bi d3 chart and I'm trying to change the thickness/width of the chart's axis lines. This following code changes the width of the line but also affects the tick's labels, drastically altering the font.

```
this.xAxis
   .style({ 'stroke': 'black', 'fill': 'none', 'stroke-width': '1px'}) 
   .call(xAxis);
```

I want to NOT impact the tick's labels. How can I only change the axis lines?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't know anything about `powerbi` but I'm guessing that `this.xAxis` is the `g` element which groups all the axis components.  A `g` doesn't style directly so all the elements underneath are inheriting from it (including the `text` elements).

So, the answer here is to get more specific with your style.  You can do this with

```
this.xAxis.select('path')
  .style({ 'stroke': 'black', 'fill': 'none', 'stroke-width': '1px'});
```

Which would style *just* the horizontal line of the axis.  Or:

```
this.xAxis.selectAll('line')
  .style({ 'stroke': 'black', 'fill': 'none', 'stroke-width': '1px'});
```

Which would style the tick marks.

**As an aside**, I wouldn't style like this at all and would probably do it through conventional CSS:

```
.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  stroke-width: 10px;
}
```

This would set the font for the entire axis `g` and set the tick marks and line across the axis to be black and thick.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. the 'path' version worked but the 'line' version didn't seem to.

I tried the CSS too...converted to LESS like this below, but it didn't seem to work either.

`// Color variables (appears count calculates by raw css)
@color0: #000000; // Appears 2 times

.axis {
 font: 10px sans-serif;
 path {
  fill: none;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: @color0;
 }
 line {
  fill: none;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: @color0;
 }
}`

Comment: @user7346922, Hmm, works with straight `d3`, you can see the css being used [in this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8952219).  Any chance you could link me a powerbi generated `d3` chart?

Comment: I'm very new to this...not sure how to link you a Power BI generated chart. I can live with the 'path' approach, but I do want to understand why the CSS approach doesn't work. I get a warning, "[less] Unknown Property," associated with `shape-rendering: crispEdges;` in Visual Studio Code. I've tried the less file both with `shape-rendering: crispEdges;` and without...same result.

Comment: @user7346922, have you tried just using CSS (and not LESS)?  Sounds like the LESS compiler is confused by an SVG only style.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure whether I can or how to use straight CSS in a Power BI visual. My understanding is Power BI is set up to use LESS, rather than CSS. I've got other examples (from Microsoft's Power BI Custom Visuals GitHub master repo) that have what you answered me originally...so it should work. I'm guessing I might have something in my code overriding the styling. If I figure this out, I'll post what I learned. Thanks for your help! At least the 'path' approach works for now. :o)

Comment: how would you move the text further away from the axis? (i'm rendering 4k frames, they stick side by side)